# Android Opengl 2d side scrolling game design decision

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm currently playing around with a 2D side scrolling platform game but I am unable to get the background to scroll. I've looked around the internet and have found a couple of tutorials, but I want to do it by drawing within OpenGL itself that make up the background.  There are obstacles on the background and a player which moves diagonally along a road. The background appears to move in diagonal direction.

I have also seen a few android game engines like andEngine and an open source project like http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/

but unable to decide which one should be used as a starting point. I read in a few blogs for andEngine that it does not allow vertical scrolling so not sure if I should move ahead with it.

Answer (score 0):

Get Corona SDK from anscomobile.com.

Comment: Looks promising but I am looking for an open source game engine/ SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Side scrolling using OpenGL isn't very hard to do, but if you're just beginning with OpenGL, you do have something of a learning curve ahead of you. One library that might help you is [Cocos2d for Android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/), which is free and open source, based on the excellent [Cocos2d for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) library. The iPhone version of the library is mature, stable, and robust. I have no idea what the state of the Android library is, but it's worth looking into.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I have already started structuring the app like replicaisland http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/